# how can i sum dataframe columns on other columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

```
ID    Product  quantity
9626     a       1
9626     b       1
9626     c       1
6600     f       1
6600     a       1
6600     d       1
```

And I want to join rows by ID.
Below is an example of the results.
(The quantity column is optional. This column is not necessary.)

```
ID    Product  quantity
9626     a,b,c     3
6600     a,d,f     3
```

I used merge and sum, but it did not work.

Is this problem solved only with a loop statement?

I'd appreciate it if you could provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = (df.sort_values('Product')
        .groupby('ID', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .agg({'Product':','.join, 'quantity':'sum'}))

print(df)
     ID Product  quantity
0  9626   a,b,c         3
1  6600   a,d,f         3
```